# Работа внутри группы LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо сделать сортировку, подсчет и удаление повторяющихся элементов(только после подсчета) внутри группы. 
Есть входная последовательность, скажем"(aaa aa bbb bb ddd dd)". Необходимо сделать группы, ключ будет первая буква строки. Это все сделал посредством Split и LINQ

```
String[] s = list[0].ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var words = s.GroupBy(t => t.Substring(0, 1)).Select(alf => new { Name = alf.Key, Count = alf.Count(), Full = alf.Select(t => t) }).OrderBy(alf=>alf.Name);
```

Подскажите, как работать с данными внутри группы.

Пример входной последовательности:

> aAaa aa vvv vv aaaa bbBb, vvv. D vvv dd

Пример выходной последовательности

> a
>
> aaaa 2
>
> aa 1
>
> b
>
> bbbb 1
>
> d
>
> d 1
>
> dd 1
>
> v
>
> vvv 3
>
> vv 1

Comment: Приведи пару примеров входных и ожидаемых выходных данных

Comment: Пример входной последовательности:
aAaa aa vvv vv aaaa bbBb, vvv. D vvv dd 
Пример выходной последовательности
a
aaaa 2

aa 1

b
bbbb 1

d
d 1

dd 1

v
vvv 3

vv 1

Comment: количество встречающихся повторений

Comment: Перепишите тогда вопрос, в вопросе требуется только удаление элементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна по сути группировка внутри групп, ничего сложного, но получается чуть более громоздко и надо чуть больше держать в голове и быть внимательным:

```
var source = "aAaa aa vvv vv aaaa bbBb, vvv. D vvv dd";
var words = source.ToLower().Split(" .,".ToCharArray(),
                                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var groups = words.GroupBy(w => w[0])
                  .Select(g => new {
                      key = g.Key,
                      content = g.GroupBy(w => w)
                                 .Select(c => new { word = c.Key, count = c.Count() })
                                 //.OrderByDescending(b => b.word.Length)
                                 .ToList()
                  })
                  .OrderBy(a => a.key)
                  .ToList();
foreach (var a in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.key);
    foreach (var b in a.content)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.word + " " + b.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает как должное

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать то же самое, но чуть чуть попроще

```
var result = words.GroupBy(x=>x).GroupBy(x=>x.Key[0]).OrderBy(x=>x.Key);    
foreach(var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Key);               
    foreach(var g in r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{g.Key} {g.Count()}");
    }
}
```